# Regex negation with non-greedy match in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

`ibeu`

I'm trying to have a regex that will do the following: (most of which works)

Find syllables in a word, and insert some letters before the first vowel in the syllable.  Because of the challenges that this presents, the string above has already been modified before running it through the hack of a lex that I wrote for it.

I have this regex that I'm trying to use on the above string:

`word.match(/(.*?)([^aeo]?u)(.*?)/)`

Given the constraints of the regex (mainly the `u` not preceded by `a, e, or o`, I expect nothing to match that regex, but I end up with the following:

`#<MatchData "ibeu" 1:"ibe" 2:"u">`

I'm sure this is something stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Finding syllables is a non-trivial task. Given the same string, the syllable boundaries depend on the language. You need natural language processing to do that.

Comment: Yeah, for the most part, I have it working for my purposes, its not perfect, but it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want negative look-behind:

```
(.*?)(?<![aeo])u
```

It matches any `u` that is not preceded by `aeo`. I am not sure what you actually want to do, so I just include the `(.*?)` in front like your current regex. The `(.*?)` at the back will always match an empty string, so it is redundant and can be removed.

Your current solution fails since `[^aeo]` is made optional. It can't simply be fixed by removing `?`, since it seems you also want to match `u` when it is at the beginning of the string or when there are multiple `u` in a row.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  I had tried a negative lookbehind, but I must've been using it incorrectly or something.